# Lists in a vscode view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create an extension for vscode; I need my view to be populated with a list as in the image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WOyo.jpg

I can't seem to find any reference to a list in the vscode api page, and I've got tree view (kinda) figured out, but that doesn't seem to solve my problem since my list items will have multiple sets of data.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you provide an example of "multiple sets of data"? Can you display this data using a multilevel tree view?

Comment: @MattBierner let's just say for the sake of list item limits I need to display at least an item `title, description, author and release date`. A normal tree item takes only a `title` and `description`. It wouldn't work in my case from UX standponit.

Comment: Extensions are currently pretty limited in how they can format tree nodes. As a workaround, could you display that information as child items of the node?

Comment: @MattBierner Assuming the child items could select the parent when clicked and not be selectable themselves, by adding small icons too I can see that as a work-around. Is the above currently possible with vscode extensions?